# Find the missing workflow

Tags: workflow

Attempting to access Galleries --> Workflows (MOSS) generates an error:

```
Failed to find the XML file at location '12\Template\Features\...COLETTEWF\feature.xml'
```

This workflow(?) no longer exists. We found a nice article that reports on features (by GUID) that are noted in some system file but don't actually exist, but because it found three more than the one we were looking for, we're trying to match GUID to (missing) workflow.

It must have been installed at Farm level, as all site collection galleries report this error.

I'm seeing no STSADM command to list all workflows (or would it only list those that still exist?)

If Galleries --> Workflow cannot list workflows, any other source of this information?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK, we took the plunge and deleted the orphan GUIDs discovered by the code referenced in the link below. Each proved to be a test workflow created back before the system was put into production. The actual workflows had long disappeared but something deep down still had record of them.

This site provided the code that generated the orphan GUIDs. As I say, when we couldn't go further than seeing the description-less GUIDs, we simply closed our eyes and deleted the GUIDs. Worked like a charm:
[Resolving the Error "Failed to find the XML file at location ’12TemplateFeaturesFeature_Namefeature.xml’"](https://web.archive.org/web/20151022051008/http://blogs.msdn.com:80/b/tehnoonr/archive/2009/02/15/resolving-the-error-failed-to-find-the-xml-file-at-location-12-template-features-feature-name-feature-xml.aspx)

Answer (score 0):

Is the feature listed in Site Collection Features? You could perhaps extract the GUI from that listing then uninstall it via STSADM.

Comment: No. My guess is that although this specification occurs _somewhere_ within the system, when the system attempts to publish that fact, it cannot find enough evidence to do so, therefore the feature appears nowhere "in public."

Comment: see if you can dig it out with SharePoint Manager, again extract the GUI with that then remove from the database via STSADM.